# Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 52 A cursor with the name 'depozit' does not exist

Tags: sql-server

I execute this script, and I get these errors from SQL Server. Please, can anyone help me?

> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
> A cursor with the name 'depozit' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 52
> A cursor with the name 'depozit' does not exist.

```sql
DECLARE @dataStart datetime = '11/01/2020',
        @dataStop datetime = '11/30/2020',
        --@Depozit varchar(100), 
        @i_depozit int,
        @CodCategArt varchar(10), 
        @Miscari bit = 1  
DECLARE @raport_stoc_L1 TABLE
                        (
                            codCateg int, 
                            produs varchar(100), 
                            cod varchar(50), 
                            UM varchar(15),
                            ContContabil varchar(10), 
                            StocInitial money default(0), 
                            ValStocInitial money default(0),
                            Intrari money default(0),
                            ValIntrari money default(0),
                            Iesiri money default(0),
                            ValIesiri money default(0), 
                            StocFinal money default(0), 
                            ValStocFinal money default(0), 
                            PretUnitar money default(0)
                        )   
                                    
DECLARE depozit CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT i_depozit 
    FROM DEPOZITE
    WHERE I_DEPOZIT IN (SELECT I_DEPOZIT
                        FROM FISEARTICOLE
                        WHERE I_DOC IN (SELECT I_DOC FROM MDOCUMENTE  
                                        WHERE D_DOCUMENT BETWEEN @dataStart AND @dataStop))     

OPEN depozit 

FETCH NEXT FROM depozit INTO @i_depozit 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN                    
    DECLARE cat_art CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT I_ARTCATEG 
        FROM VIEW_ARTICOLE_L1
        WHERE I_ARTICOL IN (SELECT I_ARTICOL
                            FROM FISEARTICOLE
                            WHERE I_DOC IN (SELECT I_DOC FROM MDOCUMENTE 
                                            WHERE D_DOCUMENT BETWEEN @dataStart AND @dataStop))

    OPEN cat_art 

    FETCH NEXT FROM cat_art INTO @CodCategArt   

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @raport_stoc_L1                                    
            EXEC [dbo].[sp_RapGestL1_v1_costi]
                        @dataStart, 
                        @dataStop, 
                        @i_depozit,
                        --@Depozit ,
                        @CodCategArt, 
                        @Miscari

        FETCH NEXT FROM cat_art INTO @CodCategArt   
    END

    CLOSE cat_art
    DEALLOCATE cat_art

    FETCH NEXT FROM depozit INTO @i_depozit

    CLOSE depozit
    DEALLCOATE depozit
END

SELECT * FROM @raport_stoc_L1
```

Comment: You're missing an `END` before the `CLOSE depozit ...... the last `END` needs to be **before** the `CLOSE depozit` call....

Comment: What is `sp_RapGestL1_v1_costi`? That isn't a documented or undocumented special procedure. User Stored Procedure should not start with `sp_` as the prefix is reserved by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

It's becasue you are closing your cursor early after first run
, you need to move `CLOSE/DEALLOCATE depozit` command lines after your cursor loop like so:

```
declare @dataStart datetime = '11/01/2020',
        @dataStop datetime = '11/30/2020',
        --@Depozit varchar(100), 
        @i_depozit int,
        @CodCategArt varchar(10), 
        @Miscari bit = 1  
declare @raport_stoc_L1 table
                                 (
                                   codCateg int, produs varchar(100), cod varchar(50), UM varchar(15),ContContabil varchar(10), StocInitial money default(0), ValStocInitial money default(0),Intrari money default(0),ValIntrari money default(0),Iesiri money default(0),ValIesiri money default(0), StocFinal money default(0), ValStocFinal money default(0), PretUnitar money default(0)
                                 )  
                                    
declare depozit cursor for select distinct i_depozit from DEPOZITE
                           where I_DEPOZIT in 
                                                 (
                                                   select I_DEPOZIT
                                                   from FISEARTICOLE
                                                   where I_DOC in (select I_DOC from MDOCUMENTE where D_DOCUMENT between @dataStart and @dataStop)
                                                  )     
open depozit 
fetch next from depozit into  @i_depozit    
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin                                                                                                
        declare cat_art cursor for select distinct I_ARTCATEG from VIEW_ARTICOLE_L1
                                   where I_ARTICOL in 
                                                         (
                                                           select I_ARTICOL
                                                           from FISEARTICOLE
                                                           where I_DOC in (select I_DOC from MDOCUMENTE where D_DOCUMENT between @dataStart and @dataStop)
                                                          )
        open cat_art 
        fetch next from cat_art into  @CodCategArt  
        while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        begin                                        
                 insert into @raport_stoc_L1                                       
                 EXEC   [dbo].[sp_RapGestL1_v1_costi]
                        @dataStart, 
                        @dataStop, 
                        @i_depozit,
                        --@Depozit ,
                        @CodCategArt, 
                        @Miscari                                                                        
                fetch next from cat_art into  @CodCategArt      
        end
                close cat_art
                deallocate cat_art
fetch next from depozit into  @i_depozit

end
close depozit
deallocate depozit

select * from @raport_stoc_L1
```